# Mongoid map / reduce or find relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have two mongoid collections:

Location and Event

```

```
class Location
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :country, type: String
  has_many :events
end

class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :date_begin, type: Date
  belongs_to :location
end
```

How can I efficiently fetch events which are in in a **specific country** on a **specific date**?

Comment: do you mean you have two MongoDB collections?  Mongoid is not the database. And you don't need map/reduce, this is a simple query question.

Comment: You're right mongodb is the db. Mongolid is the mapper.